# How to prevent beautifulsoap from extracting the information as strange symbols?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract an information with beautifulsoap, however when I do it it extracts it with very rare symbols. But when I enter directly to the page everything looks good and the page has the label `<meta charset="utf-8">`

my code is:

```
HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
        'referrer': 'https://google.com',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    }




urls = 'https://www.jcchouinard.com/web-scraping-with-python-and-requests-html/'
r = requests.get(urls, headers=HEADERS)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print (soup)
```

Nevertheless, the result I get is this:

```
J{$%X Àà’8}±ŸÅ
```

I guess it's something with the encoding, however I don't understand why since the page is utf-8.

It is worth clarifying that this only happens in some cases, since with others I manage to extract the information without problems.

**Edit:** updated with a sample url.

**Edit2:** added the headers dictionary, which is the one that generates the problem.

Comment: @MendelG updated

Comment: @MendelG updated again. The problem is in the headers, but I don't understand why

Comment: because `headers` is used by most sites to check if it's not a robot request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header. There you have `br` specified, which means [brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli) compression method. `requests` module cannot handle that. Remove `br` and the server responds without this compression method.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HEADERS = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
        'referrer': 'https://google.com',
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', # <-- remove br
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    }
        
urls = 'https://www.jcchouinard.com/web-scraping-with-python-and-requests-html/'
r = requests.get(urls, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print (soup)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="fr-FR">
<head><style>img.lazy{min-height:1px}</style><link as="script" href="https://www.jcchouinard.com/wp-content/plugins/w3-total-cache/pub/js/lazyload.min.js?x73818" rel="preload"/>

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:79.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/79.0'
}


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.prettify())


main("https://www.jcchouinard.com/web-scraping-with-python-and-requests-html/")
```

You've just to add `headers`